# Cannot get xcite to work

Tags: cross-referencing, citing

I have two documents: `a.tex`

```
\documentclass[12pt,longbibliography]{article}

\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{xr}

\begin{document} 

\section{Section}\label{sec}
Read this \cite{book}. 
\begin{equation}\label{eq}
  1+1=2
\end{equation}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{book}
  Henry James 
  \newblock Book .

\bibitem{book2}
  Mark Smith
  \newblock Book 2.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

and `b.tex`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr} 
\externaldocument{a}
\usepackage{xcite} 
\externalcitedocument{a}

\begin{document} 

Read Eq. (\ref{eq}) in \cite{book2}. 

\end{document}
```

Here I cite `book`  in `a.pdf`, and cite `book2` in `b.pdf`, and both `book` and `book2` to appear in the Reference list of `a.pdf` only. This works fine.

However, when I also need to cross reference an equation in `a.tex` from `b.tex`, I get a strange equation name in the pdf: here is b.pdf

[image]

Do you guys know a way to solve this and get a proper equation reference in b.pdf?

Answer (score 1):

Note in recent releases `xcite` is merged in to `xr` so you do not need to load both, however it should basically work the same way, and works for me in texlive 2019 giving

[image]

`a.tex` does not refer to `b` so should look like

```
\documentclass{article}


\begin{document} 
This interesting book \cite{book}. 

\begin{thebibliography}{10}    
\bibitem{book}
  M. Hill.
  \newblock Book.
  \newblock  2018.

\bibitem{book2}
  M. Grace.
  \newblock Other book.
  \newblock  2019.
\end{thebibliography}
\end{document}
```

and you need to process that first, and not delete `a.aux`.

Then `b.tex` should look like

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xr} 
%\usepackage{xcite}
\externaldocument{a}
%\externalcitedocument{a}

\begin{document} 
Please read \cite{book2}.
\end{document}
```

and you need to process that with `a.aux` being available.  On older releases you will need the `xcite` lines uncommented.

Comment: I have implemented your reccommendations, and it still does not work for me.

Comment: add your `a.aux` and `b.log`  to your question so we can see what it is doing

Comment: You are right, this was not working because of a silly mistake of mine. However, I tried to cross reference also equations, and I get a very strange behavior, please see my revised answer.

Comment: It's best not to change the question after answers posted. Probably you are using hyperref which does not work with xr, see xr-hyper package @Juan

Comment: Sorry, I saw your comment after I changed it. Anyways, you are right that the reason was the conflict between xr and hyperref!

Answer (score 0):

As it was pointed out in a comment, the issue was a conflict between the `hyperref` and `xr` packages. By removing `hyperref` and replacing `xr` with `xr-hyper`, it works. Here is `a.tex`:

```
\documentclass[12pt,longbibliography]{article}

\begin{document} 

\section{Section}\label{sec}
Read this \cite{book}. 
\begin{equation}\label{eq}
  1+1=2
\end{equation}

\begin{thebibliography}{10}

\bibitem{book}
  Henry James 
  \newblock Book .

\bibitem{book2}
  Mark Smith
  \newblock Book 2.

\end{thebibliography}

\end{document}
```

and here is `b.tex`

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xr-hyper} 
\externaldocument{a}
\usepackage{xcite} 
\externalcitedocument{a}

\begin{document} 

Read Eq. (\ref{eq}) in \cite{book2}. 

\end{document}
```